# Как различать пользователей с одинаковыми именами?

Tags: поддержка, дефект, статус-так-задумано

Почему система допускает, чтобы у разных пользователей были одинаковые имена (например, посмотрите сколько раз встречается Наталья)? Как различать пользователей с одинаковыми именами?

Answer (score 1):

На сайтах Stack Exchange допускается дублирование имен. Различать пользователей можно, например, по аватарке, которая, как правило, у каждого профиля уникальна.

Comment: Неужели все "тезки" получают уведомление, если  одному из них адресовано сообщение (@Имя)?

Comment: @М_Г нет, уведомления приходят только тем пользователям, которые оставили ранее комментарий или являются авторами сообщения.

Comment: Для меня это неприятный сюрприз. Выходит, я никак не могу привлечь внимание участника, который не учавствовал в обсуждении данного вопроса?

Comment: @М_Г увы, нет. Можно попробовать создать отдельный вопрос о добавлении такой функции.